# Android: list_view focus always returning to first item

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using two list-view's list_A and list_B with same number of list items, when navigated from list_A to list_B, i want to set focus of list_B to same position of list_A item, to do this i am using

```
list_B.setSelection(list_A_cur);
list_B.setFocusable(true);
list_B.requestFocus();
```

it moves the focus correctly at first but after some time focus goes back to first item of list_B.

Comment: could you also paste your code of instantiating list_A_cur and the related assignments?

Comment: list_A_cur is been used as a global variable to keep reference for the  navigation on KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, similarly it is incremented or decremented on KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN and KEYCODE_DPAD_UP

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP: {
 if (cur_focus == 0) { //i.e if on list_A 
  if (list_A_cur > 0)
   --list_A_cur;
                       }
         }

similarly for DPAD_DOWN
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP: {
 if (cur_focus == 0) { //i.e if on list_A 
  if (list_A_cur < list_A.getSize()-1)
   ++list_A_cur;
                       }
         }

Comment: huh? isn't list_A_cur an integer that just takes the index of list_a? It seems you are using the same variable for different purposes and that is causing a mess up. Also - when are you calling setSelection? Again - it would be highly appreciated to provide more of the related code - 1 list_A_cur assignment and 2 the callst to the block with "setSelection"

Comment: @ile 
1. list_A_cur gives the value same as list_A index, i checked it, the code given previously was to use in navigation back to the same item and it initialized as private int list_A_cur; and initialized to zero in oncreate(),
2. call to setSelection of list_B made on KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT

     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT: {
   if (cur_focus == 0) {
                         list_B.setSelection(list_A_cur);
                                list_B.setFocusable(true);
                                list_B.requestFocus();
    cur_focus = 1;
    break;
   }